# Add Current User id to trigger sql query hair_trigger gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, triggers, rails-postgresql, database-trigger

I am using hair_trigger gem and in my model, i want to keep changes to some columns.

```
trigger.after(:insert).declare("#{current_user.id} as current_user_id") do
    "insert into histories (item_type, item_id, field, old_value, new_value, changed_by, created_at, updated_at) values ('CaseStatus', NEW.id, 'loan_case_id', '', NEW.loan_case_id, current_user_id, current_timestamp, current_timestamp);"
  end
```

I thought i could be able to declare and pass the current_user id in my query so that i can save the user who made the changes but i get an error about  `'undefined variable current_user'`

Does anyone know how i can be able to save the user who triggered the changes using hair_trigger gem in a Rails Model.

Much appreciated

Comment: But have you taken a look at the `papertrail` gem, it does exactly what you're looking for, tracks changes to models.

Comment: I know this is not a direct response to your question, but have you considered using an audit gem? Take a look at https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited or https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Comment: I have never used this gem, is it even possible to send parameters to the trigger function like this?

Comment: @Iceman To be fair, I just assumed it could but you have a very good point.

Comment: @Iceman i know about papertrail and audit gem but both gems store their object_changes in text format but hair_triggers allows me to track differently

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated in the comments you won't have access to `current_user` in your models by design. One way to circumvent that is to use the current thread. People often try to stay away from that because it's not concurrency friendly when using web servers like `Puma`. I'd strongly recommend using an Auditing gem like [Audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) or [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail), but if you want to keep your approach you can do something like this.

```
# User.rb
def self.current_user
  Thread.current[:current_user] ||= nil
end

def self.current_user=(user)
  Thread.current[:current_user] = user
end
```

You can set that variable in every request you have a current_user, like in the ApplicationController using a before filter or even an around filter to clean it up afterwards.

```
# ApplicationController.rb
before_action :share_current_user

def share_current_user
  User.current_user = current_user
end
```

Also, take a look at [RequestStore](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store). It should make your life easier to accomplish this.